# how to add :active to menu element dynamically

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am building the menu dynamically in my single page angularjs web app.

```
`<li ng-repeat="m in menu"><a href="#{{m.url}}">{{m.name}}</a></li>
```

I want to add active class to the anchor tag to show what is the current page selected.

`a` tag CSS:

```
 .cl-effect-4 a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.cl-effect-4 a:hover::after,
.cl-effect-4 a:focus::after,.cl-effect-4 a:active::after {
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

I have tried `ng-class="{active:getClass(m.url)}"` but this did not work because it just adds class named active. I need to make the anchor tag active  by property.

Comment: not sure i completely follow but do you mean to use `ng-attr-class` ?

Comment: @Pogrindis m sorry i m new to angularjs. What does ng-attr-class do?

Comment: It binds attributes, but I don't see why adding the active class would not work.. what is your `getClass` function ?

Comment: $scope.getClass = function (path) {
            if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) {
                return 'active';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        } this is my getClass . I dont want to add a class 'active' i want to make the anchor tag active by using property :active @Pogrindis

Comment: are you using `ng-route` or `ui-route` ?

Comment: @AnasOmar i m using `ui-route`

Comment: try this out `<li ng-repeat="m in menu"><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="{{m.url}}">{{m.name}}</a></li>`
`

Comment: @AnasOmar I have url value not the state value. I cannot use `ui-sref` then right?

Answer (score 0):

The right side of ngClass expression in your example should be a boolean val. So 'active' will be added if getClass() is true.  You should return a true or false from the getClass function.

```
 $scope.getClass = function (path) {
          if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) { 
              return true; 
            } else { 
              return false; 
           }
```

Comment: But on inspect element action class is being added. I have tried with the boolean also. But the class gets added but not the property :active

Comment: Please clairify 'on inspect element action class is being added'

Comment: when i inspect the anchor tag i can see that the class active being added to to it